# Apache Kylin docker image fails to start

Tags: kylin

I have downloaded the Apache Kylin docker image from their site, I use the following command to run the image and it exits with code 139:

```
docker run -d -m 8G -p 7070:7070 -p 8088:8088 -p 50070:50070 -p 8032:8032 -p 8042:8042 -p 16010:16010 apachekylin/apache-kylin-standalone:3.1.0
```

It shows port 16010 has an issue but nothing in the logs

Please advise, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am one of the contributor of Kylin project, and I saw your question in mailing list. I didn't use windows as my dev machine(I use Mac OS), but I have a pc(win10) for gaming.

I installed WSL2, and latest docker desktop, and pull and start kylin container. And container existed with code 139.

[image: Start container exited with code 139]

So, I search and find the link : [https://dev.to/damith/docker-desktop-container-crash-with-exit-code-139-on-windows-wsl-fix-438#:~:text=Issue%20%3A%20Docker%20Container%20exits%20on%20Docker%20desktop,the%20kernel%20config%20to%20run%20older%20base%20images](https://dev.to/damith/docker-desktop-container-crash-with-exit-code-139-on-windows-wsl-fix-438#:%7E:text=Issue%20%3A%20Docker%20Container%20exits%20on%20Docker%20desktop,the%20kernel%20config%20to%20run%20older%20base%20images).

So, I follow the link, add `[wsl2] kernelCommandLine = vsyscall=emulate` in `C://users/[your user name]/.wslconfig` . After, start and build Kylin container success.

[image: Start container success]

Comment: Thanks...really appreciate the help.

Comment: If my answer could help to fix this issue, could you please accpect this answer.